# Can't get smalldate values printed

Tags: php, sql, odbc, sybase

Im trying to print values from a Sybase view using php and odbc. I get all the values printed except the smalldate values.

Does anyone knows why this happens?

Im using the code :

```
$db = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pwd);

$query = odbc_exec($db, 'select * from GP_Vw_Cons_Faltas where DataInicio = "2018/11/28"
');

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($query)){
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($row);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted to varchar on sql

```
$query = odbc_exec($db, 'select Convert(varchar(20),DataFim,103) as DataFim from GP_Vw_Cons_Faltas where Codigo=5410
');
```